# Is cin a proper file object?

Tags: c++, file, stdin

As in, can I pass `cin` to any function that accepts an ifstream object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`std::cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) is not a file stream, but an input stream, or [`istream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/).  You can pass it to any function that accepts an istream.

Comment: Though I believe calls trying to seek or get the length of the stream will fail, though not 100% sure on this.

Answer (score 4):

`std::cin` is a `std::istream`.

There is little difference between class `istream` and its derivative `ifstream`. `ifstream` allows you to open and close files, providing `open()`, `close()`, and `is_open()`, and a constructor which calls `open()` — and that's it!

If your function doesn't use those methods, it should take an `istream&` instead of an `ifstream&`.